# Conditional checking with class names not working with tomcat in primefaces xhtml

Tags: tomcat, jsf, primefaces, el

I am using rendered attribute like `rendered="#{(column[0].class.name == 'java.lang.String')}"`. It was working fine with my wildfly server. I have switched to tomcat and using `class.name ==` is creating problems with tomcat. I use `class.name ==` to conditionally check for my internal classes inside the `value` attribute of `<h:outputText>` as well but till the time this line is being used in the code the page would go blank and as soon as this line is removed the page would load fine. Is there a way to handle this in a different way so that the existing code works fine with minor manipulations and why does tomcat create this problem?

Comment: Are both server using the same EL version?

Comment: Yes both the servers are using same EL version